# Handling Error 2001 on Cancel - MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, refresh, ms-access-2016

I have a form that I am requerying on the click of a button using

```
DoCmd.Requery
```

This works and I am able to requery the form based on the criteria I specified in my query table. However, if I cancel the requery, rather than click OK, I get an error (2001). How can I have the form remain as is if the user cancels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
  On Error Resume Next
  DoCmd.Requery
  On Error GoTo 0
```